# Which event would get triggered when I press "color" type in HTML5

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to store the hex values of colors into my product table using Ajax without a button click. I have tried using `change` and `click` events but neither of them works in this case. I would like to know which event should I use to fetch the value(hex) value using Ajax(Jquery).

```js
$(document).on("click", "#prod_color", function(event){
 event.preventDefault();
 var a=$("#prod_color").val();
 console.log(a);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tr>
  <th>Color</th>
    <td><input type="color" name="color" id="prod_color"></td>
  </tr>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is `change`. Though it will only get triggered when the color value actually change which means if you are trying to play with the color graph and the value is `#000000` always then it would not trigger change.

```js
$(document).on("change", "#prod_color", function(event) {
  var a = $("#prod_color").val();
  console.log(a);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="color" name="color" id="prod_color">
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man! I guess, the cache of my browser was creating the problem. And I would be grateful if you could upvote me.

Comment: @DavidThomas I spent a lot of time using the events in question but somehow things didn't work out. Wanted to make sure if I was on the right track so I asked only after checking out on stackoverflow. Only after getting an answer did I realize it was the cache in my browser which was creating a problem. Although I had `disabled` the cache but thereafter went on and deleted the entire history and cookies etc. And then it worked. So for my honest attempt I shouldn't be downvoted. I come here to the community cuz I am a novice and I respect you all. Hence you guys should respect me too!

Comment: @Don'tDownvoteMe correct.. I guess what you want from me is to cancel the downvote... but hoenstly I didnt downvote your question.. it is someone else.. :)

Comment: @void I wanted you to upvote me for my effort but it is totally upto you.It would be great if you could do the same, if not, I still would be thankful to you for the help. See ya around!